# PHP regex with quotes

Tags: php, regex

I want to match all href values in my page content. I wrote regex for that and tested it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/#pcre)

```
href[ ]*=[ ]*("|')(.+?)\1
```

This finds all my href values properly. If I use

```
href[ ]*=[ ]*(?:"|')(.+?)(?:"|')
```

its even better since I do not have to use certain group later.

With " and ' in regex string I cannot run the regex properly with

```php
$matches = array();  
$pattern = "/href[ ]*=[ ]*("|')(.+?)\1/"; // syntax error 
$numOfMatches = preg_match_all($pattern, $pattern, $matches);  
print_r($matches);
```

If I "escape" double quote and thus repair the syntax error I get no matches.

So - what is the correct way to apply the given regex in PHP?

Thanks for any help

Notes:

- [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) won't help since I need to pass legit string first
- escaping all the special chars   `\ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -` didn't help either

**EDIT**: Ok, I see I really shouldn't be doing this with regex. Could you please provide some helpful DOM parsers or any other tool I 'should' use with PHP for instance ?

Comment: For finding all href links regex is not the right tool.

Comment: To escape chars just use the backslash like: `\"` (quotes) or `\(` (brace) or \\ (backslash)

Comment: Haha, this escaping thing doesn't let me highlight \\ as code ^^

Comment: Don't use regexes. This'd be far easier with DOM+XPath: `//*[@href]` and done. And just because you ARE defining a regex doesn't excuse you from PHP's string syntax rules. If your string contains the same quote that delimits the string, that internal quote must be escaped.

Comment: Are you trying to [parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/53114)? Why not using a proper parser?

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2812842) Read a **basic** XPath tutorial and you'll see that returning all href attributes in a document is easy. Regex will kill you one day.

Comment: Thanks guys, I see I really shouldn't use regex here. Please see my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use this regex to make it work. Next time I will definitely try with DOM parser :)

```
$regexForHREF = "/href[ ]*=[ ]*(?:\"|')(.+?)(?:\"|')/";
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the following should work:

```
/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU
```

Given the nature of the WWW there are always going to be cases where the regular expression breaks down. Small changes to the patterns can fix these.

spaces around the = after href:

```
/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU
```

matching only links starting with http:

```
/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)(http[^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU
```

single quotes around the link address:

```
/<a\s[^>]*href=([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU
```

[Source](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/)