# PHP: preg_match search and replace href

Tags: php, preg-match

i have html and contain many links like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain1.com">Click Me</a>
```

i would like to:

copy its original link: **http://www.mydomain1.com**

append text infront it: **test.php?url=http://www.mydomain1.com**

so that the final output for all href to become:

```
<a href="test.php?url=http://www.mydomain1.com">Click Me</a>
```

how to do this?

Comment: do not parse HTML with regex. use DOM parser instead.

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ or https://code.google.com/p/ganon/ also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782250/php-regex-with-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually not a good practice to use regex on HTML. Use DOM parser instead:

- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
- https://code.google.com/p/ganon/

If you really need to, you can use my regex from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782250/php-regex-with-quotes) answer:

```
$regexForHREF = "/href[ ]*=[ ]*(?:\"|')(.+?)(?:\"|')/";
```

to get the href value and then you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to add your "test.php?url=".